# Monit HTTP Status code gives a syntax error

Tags: monit

My systems are running monit 5.19. When I start Monit, I see the error `syntax error 'status'`

Status appears to be supported since 5.8 so I'm not sure what the issue is.

It is being caused by the  following directive.

```
check host nlb  with address   host
if failed
  port 443
  protocol HTTPS
  request "/healthcheck"
  ssl options {verify: disable}
  timeout 15 seconds
  status = 200
then restart
```

Comment: I don't really know Monit, but might it be `status 200`? All the other lines don't have the `=`. Edit: Meh, that's likely not it according to https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#HTTP. Confusing syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `status` clause is part of the `proto http` statement so needs to come before the `ssl` line (which **isn't** part of `proto http`). See the definition of `proto http` at https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#HTTP ...

```
 PROTO(COL) HTTP
     [USERNAME "string"]
     [PASSWORD "string"]
     [REQUEST "string"]
     [STATUS operator number]
     [CHECKSUM checksum]
     [HTTP HEADERS list of headers]
     [CONTENT < "=" | "!=" > STRING]
```

Version of file that doesn't give error is

```
check host nlb  with address   host
if failed
  port 443
  protocol HTTPS
  request "/healthcheck"
  status = 200
  ssl options {verify: disable}
  timeout 15 seconds
then restart
```